# Cannot open OpenOffice because the developer is not certified

Tags: security, open-office

Since the update to Mac OS 10.11.6 the security preferences are not working properly. I'm trying to open OpenOffice and, even though I have disabled limitations, it is refusing to open and keeps telling me that the settings need changing.

Comment: hm, it seems that downloading and reinstalling again and opening via context menu might be a workaround for this.

Comment: May I suggest to change to LibreOffice? Never had such kind of problems, including the latest version.

Comment: The app itself isn't relevant, this is about the security settings in MacOS. I do have LibreOffice installed but I find it less stable than OpenOffice and it has a worse UI.

Answer (score 1):

After failing to open the app, go to System Preferences -> Security. It should refer to blocking openOffice and give you an option to open it.

Comment: It did have the option and I did click on it. It made no difference. As noted above I had to reinstall the program and go through the hoops several times even though I had all restrictions disabled.

Answer (score -2):

instead of clicking on the app select open then it opens

Comment: Except that isn't what happened.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review